# tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU outcome is not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, metrics

I am training a model using UNET architecture on Colab for 3D multiclass segmentation. I am using tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU for the metrics but the outcomes for all epochs are not improving. Where have I done wrong?

```
import random
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

########################################################################################################################
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(physical_devices))
try:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
except:
  # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
  pass
########################################################################################################################

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nibabel as nib
from scipy import ndimage
from tqdm import tqdm
import models
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import metrics
import datetime

class UpdatedMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
    def __init__(self,
                 y_true=None,
                 y_pred=None,
                 num_classes=None,
                 name=None,
                 dtype=None):
        super(UpdatedMeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes=num_classes, name=name, dtype=dtype)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

# Load training and validation data
image_count_train = os.listdir(train_image_path)
image_count_train = len(image_count_train)

image_list_train = os.listdir(train_image_path)
label_list_train = os.listdir(train_label_path)

image_count_test = os.listdir(test_image_path)
image_count_test = len(image_count_test)

image_list_test = os.listdir(test_image_path)
label_list_test = os.listdir(test_label_path)

x_train = np.zeros(shape=(image_count_train, img_height, img_width, img_depth), dtype=np.uint8)
y_train = np.zeros(shape=(image_count_train, img_height, img_width, img_depth), dtype=np.uint8)

#Loading training labels and images
for x in tqdm(range(len(image_list_train))):
    img_path = os.path.join(train_image_path, image_list_train[x])
    lbl_path = os.path.join(train_label_path, label_list_train[x])

    img = nib.load(img_path)
    img = img.get_fdata()

    while (img.ndim > 3):
        img = np.squeeze(img, axis=-1)

    lbl = nib.load(lbl_path)
    lbl = lbl.get_fdata()

    while (lbl.ndim > 3):
        lbl = np.squeeze(lbl, axis=-1)

    x_train[x] = img
    y_train[x] = lbl

x_test = np.zeros(shape=(image_count_test, img_height, img_width, img_depth), dtype=np.uint8)
y_test = np.zeros(shape=(image_count_test, img_height, img_width, img_depth), dtype=np.uint8)

print("loading test data...")
#loading test labels and images
for x in tqdm(range(len(image_list_test))):
    img_path = os.path.join(test_image_path, image_list_test[x])
    lbl_path = os.path.join(test_label_path, label_list_test[x])

    img = nib.load(img_path)
    img = img.get_fdata()

    while (img.ndim > 3):
        img = np.squeeze(img, axis=-1)

    lbl = nib.load(lbl_path)
    lbl = lbl.get_fdata()

    while (lbl.ndim > 3):
        lbl = np.squeeze(lbl, axis=-1)

    x_test[x] = img
    y_test[x] = lbl

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=-1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)
y_test = np.expand_dims(y_test, axis=-1)
x_val = np.expand_dims(x_val, axis=-1)
y_val = np.expand_dims(y_val, axis=-1)

model = models.unet(img_height, img_width, img_depth)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, mode='min', min_delta=0.001)

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

filepath = 'checkpoint_model/Version_2_ '+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+'.h5'
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath,  verbose=1, save_best_only=True)


model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
                                       name='Adam'),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[UpdatedMeanIoU(num_classes=5)]
    #metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=5)]
    )

history = model.fit(x=x_train,
                    y=y_train,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, checkpoint_callback]
                    )
```

> Epoch 1: val_loss improved from inf to 0.04398, saving model to
> my_model.h5 1603/1603 [==============================] - 498s
> 308ms/step - loss: 0.1729 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.1969
>
> Epoch 2: val_loss improved from 0.04398 to 0.04363, saving model to
> my_model.h5 1603/1603 [==============================] - 492s
> 307ms/step - loss: 0.0425 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.1987
>
> Epoch 3: val_loss improved from 0.04363 to 0.04321, saving model to
> my_model.h5 1603/1603 [==============================] - 492s
> 307ms/step - loss: 0.0423 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.1987
>
> Epoch 4: val_loss improved from 0.04321 to 0.04309, saving model to
> my_model.h5 1603/1603 [==============================] - 492s
> 307ms/step - loss: 0.0422 - updated_mean_io_u: 0.1987

Comment: They seem to be improving, only the improvements are very small per epoch, you might want to mess around with the hyperparameters of the model and training to see if you can get the model to converge faster.

Comment: I have tried with batch size = 12, epochs = 20 and batch size = 4, epochs = 10 for my 10000 sample size, and also learning rate = 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, but the updated mean iou still remained the same for all epochs.

Comment: I even downgraded the tensorflow version to 2.4.0 with cuda 11.0 and it still did not work too. (It already did not work on tensorflow 2.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved! It was because of os.listdir when it tried to get the list of the dataset folders. The list was not returned in sequence on Colab and it was fixed with sorted method. But the problem did not exist on Spyder.